# Convert global coordinates to local

Tags: matrix, three.js, coordinate-transformation

A particle system based on [three.js](https://threejs.org/)' [`Points`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Points).
Internally I am treating the particles as global (with position and velocity [vectors](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3)) and update the `Points` geometry accordingly.
It works nicely if the `Points` object is global (and static).
I need to change this so the `Points` object moves through the Scene (as child of the  "particle emitter"). That requires converting global coordinates for each particle to local coordinates for the `Points` object geometry.

I have attempted the following:

```
local = globalParticle.position.clone().applyMatrix4( movingPointsObject.matrixWorld.invert() );
```

and

```
local = movingPointsObject.worldToLocal( globalParticle.position );
```

with different results.

The former seems to work in principle, but the particles appear to have duplicates depending on the Z-rotation of the `Points` object (they align when rotation is PI).
The latter causes the particles to rotate quickly, giving the appearance of a ring.

What's going on?

https://jsfiddle.net/b7nLorvf/

or

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(480, 480);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color("gray");

const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-2, 2, 2, -2, 1, 2);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 2);
scene.add(camera);

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.75); // soft white light
scene.add(light);

const bgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
const bmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff00ff
});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(bgeometry, bmaterial);
scene.add(cube);

let pgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
//pgeometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([], 3));
const pmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  size: 2
}); //, depthTest:true } );
let points = new THREE.Points(pgeometry, pmaterial);
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(1);
points.add(axesHelper);

//const global = true;
const global = false;
if (global) {
  scene.add(points); // global
} else {
  cube.add(points); // local
}

let particles = [];

let lt = 0,
  dt = 0;

function animate(ms) {

  dt = (ms - lt) / 1000;
  lt = ms;

  // move emitter
  const a = ms / 1000;
  cube.position.x = Math.cos(a) * 1;
  cube.position.y = Math.sin(a) * 1;
  cube.rotation.z = a;

  // particles
  particles.push({
    position: cube.position.clone(),
    velocity: new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0).applyEuler(cube.rotation),
    life: 1
  });
  for (let p of particles) {
    p.life -= dt;
  }
  particles = particles.filter(p => {
    return p.life > 0.0;
  });

  let v = [];
  for (let p of particles) {
    p.position.add(p.velocity.clone().multiplyScalar(dt));

        let vertex;
    if (global) {
      vertex = p.position;
    } else {
      //vertex = p.position.clone().applyMatrix4( points.matrixWorld.invert() );
      vertex = points.worldToLocal( p.position );
    }
    v.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
  }
  pgeometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(v, 3));


  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.148.0/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The former works in conjunction with

```
movingPointsObject.updateWorldMatrix(true, true);
```

Inspired by `worldToLocal`, see [`three.js/Object3D.js#L256`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/03349e98aa1f57a97433c0a3f17697594fdc0997/src/core/Object3D.js#L256).